# 2001 Chevy Silverado PU Low Beams

Tags: chevrolet, headlight, silverado

I have a 2001 Chevy Silverado PU. My problem is the only way my low beams will come on, is if I tilt the steering wheel to its lowest position. Do you think this a short in the wiring going to the dimmer in the blinker shaft?

Comment: "tilt the steering wheel to its lowest position" Do you mean the lowest position of a vertically adjustable steering column? Just asking to make things more clear. If so, it indeed sounds like a wiring issue. Could be a loose connector that is still hanging by a thread, or a wire break. A shortcircuit  is less plausible i'd say. For that you have to have loose bare metal showing wires hanging around that touch a part of bare metal frame.

Comment: Just to ensure we know for sure, does your truck have the switch on the dash to turn them on ... possibly have the auto headlight feature?

Comment: I have no idea why you were downvoted.  It is almost certainly a short in the wiring.  Is your truck a 1500?  Is it the HD model?  What engine does it have?  That info will help us find wiring diagrams.

Answer (score 1):

Technically a short is a current pathway that bypasses the intended load – often to ground (or neutral in AC wiring). This often results in a large current that could damage wiring and other components due to overheating, that's what the fuses are for and they usually blow when there is a short to ground.

So, no, you probably don't have a short. What more likely is that the wiring in the steering column has been damaged and when you tilt the wheel up it opens the circuit. Pretty much what you're suggesting.

What you'll need to do is to pull off the covers on the steering column to see if you can get at the wiring. Look for any signs of mechanical damage and also more the harness around to see if you can reproduce the problem. Odds are that you'll find a wire that's been pinched and partially cut.

Here's some photos of the process of splicing a cable with uninsulated butt splices and heat shrink tubing:

[image]

If that's the case you can probably repair it with a butt splice, but don't just do that blindly – figure out how the damaged happened and how to prevent it from happening again.

Butt splices come in both uninsulated (bare metal like the ones above) and insulated varieties. Both do the same job (reconnecting the wires). The uninsulated are somewhat smaller and may be easier to fit into tight spaces, just make sure that they get insulated somehow – tape, heat shrink tubing, wire loom, will all do the job.